# How do I create and pass string array to a sub in Excel VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

VBA arrays are new to me and it seems like there are multiple ways to create string arrays.

- I believe I need to create a [dynamic array](http://patorjk.com/programming/tutorials/vbarrays.htm)
- But I can't find any examples how to pass [dynamic arrays](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/PassingAndReturningArrays.htm) to a subroutine

I know how many items there need to be in the array by the count of the User range (so maybe I don't need a dynamic array??). I'm having trouble passing the array through to another Subroutine.

The thought process is as follows:

1. Iterate through a list of user names
2. Create a sheet for each
3. Save each user name in an array as I iterate through
4. In another Subroutine, select all the sheets I created and save as a PDF

Below is my code. I'm getting Run-time error 9 - Subscript out of range (Referring to the array object)

I appreciate any help! Thank you!

```
Sub CreateAllDashboards(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date)
'Used to iterate through the list of users and call the Sub to create Dashboards

Dim UserNameRangeStart As Range
Set UserNameRangeStart = Range("UserName")
Dim SheetNames() As String

'Cyle through users
For i = 1 To GetUserNameRange().CounT
    'Some code
    ReDim Preserve SheetNames(i)
    SheetNames(i) = UserNameRangeStart.Offset(i, 0).Value
Next i

Call CreatePDF(EndDate, SheetNames) 'Also tried SheetNames()

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub CreatePDF(FileDate As Date, ByRef SheetNames As Variant)

Dim FilePath As String, FileName As String

FilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
FileName = "Production Dashboards - " & Format(FileDate, "mmddyy") & ".pdf"


ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNames).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    FileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array parameter is not a problem it is passed correctly to method `CreatePDF(...)`. The parameter type can be changed to `SheetNames() As String` but `SheetNames As Variant` works as well.

Then the `Run-time error 9 - Subscript out of range` is raised here `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNames).Select` because the array `SheetNames` contains invalid sheet name, which is the very first item. This item is an empty string and empty string is not valid as a sheet name.

[image]

In the `For Next` loop index starts with value `1` but the array starts with `0`. So the very first item of the array `SheetNames` remains untouched and is finally an empty string. To solve it set the lower bound in `ReDim` explicitly to `1`. HTH

*(Note: if you omit lower bound then `Option Base` is used and if no `Option Base` is specified then `0` is used.)*

```
'Cyle through users
For i = 1 To GetUserNameRange().Count
    'Some code
    ReDim Preserve SheetNames(1 To i)
    SheetNames(i) = UserNameRangeStart.Offset(i, 0).value
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

**I would change this:**
`Sub CreatePDF(FileDate As Date, ByRef SheetNames As Variant)`

**To this:**
`Sub CreatePDF(FileDate As Date, SheetNames() As String)`

**But your problem is at this line:**
`ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNames).Select`

Edited from dee's comment:
You can put an array of sheet names in `.Sheets()` but **without** empty rows.  So in your sub "CreateAllDashboards" do this:

```
ReDim Preserve SheetNames(i - 1)
SheetNames(i - 1) = UserNameRangeStart.Offset(i, 0).Value
```

and you could read [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) about arrays in VBA.

Comment: Sheets(Array("Sheet4", "Sheet5")) i valid, have a look e.g. here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193217%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Exactly, that is my case as well :-)

Answer (score -1):

I've tested the following using a single sheet workbook with a range named Users and another named FileDate. It does what you asked.

The reason for the `Run-time error 9 - Subscript out of range` error is that you have to reference the array element. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNames).Select` will throw an error but `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNames(x)).Select` won't (as long as x is initialised and within the bounds of the array)

```
Sub PopulateArray()
Dim user As Range
Dim SheetNames As Variant

    ReDim SheetNames(1 To 1) 'Initialise the array
    For Each user In [Users]
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        With Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
            .Name = user.Value2
            .[A1] = user.Value2 'you can't print a blank sheet!
        End With
        SheetNames(UBound(SheetNames)) = user.Value2
        ReDim Preserve SheetNames(1 To UBound(SheetNames) + 1)
    Next user
    ReDim Preserve SheetNames(1 To UBound(SheetNames) - 1) 'Delete the last element
    Call CreatePDF([FileDate], SheetNames)
End Sub

Sub CreatePDF(FileDate As Date, ByRef SheetNames As Variant)

Dim FilePath As String, FileName As String
Dim x As Long

    FilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" 'Note backslash added to path.
    FileName = "Amtec Production Dashboards - " & Format(FileDate, "mmddyy")

    For x = 1 To UBound(SheetNames)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNames(x)).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
            FileName & SheetNames(x) & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
             IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    Next x
End Sub
```

The above demonstrates how to parse an array to another sub as requested but you could integrate the CreatePDF code into the calling sub fairly easily too.

Comment: I started my answer the same way but @dee pointed me to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193217%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to show that you can, surprisingly I must say, reference an array within `.Sheets()`.  The `Run-time error 9` is thrown by the empty line in `SheetNames` array.